# TcpClient equivalent for Socket Shutdown Send or Receive

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

Concerning `System.Net.TcpClient`

I was wondering if it is possible to perform an individual shutdown on the outputstream or inputstream from a `TcpClient`.
I know, that the `NetworkStream` can be grepped with `aTcpClient.GetStream()` however, I am still figuring out to `Close()` the inbound or outbound part of it, without closing the entire Networkstream.

This is possible with the more basic `System.Net.Socket` class in which I could first send data and afterwards close it with `SocketShutdown.Send` while keeping the inputstream open untill I close it with `SocketShutdown.Receive`.

*Reference links:*

[MSDN on System.Net.Socket.shutdown()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN on System.Net.TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TcpClient has a `Client` property, which is of the type `Socket`.

Use the property to get `Socket`, so you can call `Shutdown()`.

Comment: Silly me, I should have known it was in a Decorator pattern